# It's possible to play sound from main bundle with AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer

It's possible to play sound from main bundle with AVPlayer ? It's working with URL adress from internet or ipod library but from main bundle no :( Why ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"audioFileName" withExtension:@"mp3"];
```